# How to underline text in form fields with Apache PDFBox?

Tags: java, pdfbox, underline

I am currently working on a Java application that uses Apache PDFBox to fill form fields and sign a PDF document. After the document is signed, I would like to underline the text in certain form fields.

I have been able to manipulate the text in terms of font, size, and color, but underlining the text has proven to be a challenge. I have tried adding an underline as an annotation, but this approach has not been successful.
I'm struggling to find clear instructions or examples in the PDFBox documentation or online about how to add an underline to the text in a form field after the document is signed.

Here are my questions:

Is it possible to underline text in a form field using PDFBox after signing the document? If so, how can it be done?
If underlining is not possible through the default appearance string or as an annotation, is there any workaround or alternative solution?
Any guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Comment: The PDF specification mentions border style "U" in the border style dictionary. I don't remember if this has an effect in for form fields widget annotations, PDFBox uses it for rendering only for link annotations. Maybe create such a file and see what happens.

Comment: It is a bad idea to try and apply such changes _after signing_. The natural way to underline would be to add an underline annotation, but adding new annotations may not be allowed depending on the signature applied. You say that *approach has not been successful* - how did you try it, how did it fail?

Comment: My code is lengthy, but I'm attempting to create all the fields first. After that:

The first signer populates their fields and signs the document.
The second signer populates their fields and signs it again.
Everything works fine, but when I try to add an underline, it doesn't appear. This is because I haven't implemented it correctly. Therefore, I'm searching for an example to accomplish that using PDFBox 2.0.28.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr, could you please provide guidance on how to implement the "U" border style approach you mentioned?

Comment: PDBorderStyleDictionary borderULine = new PDBorderStyleDictionary();
            borderULine.setStyle(PDBorderStyleDictionary.STYLE_UNDERLINE);
   borderULine.setWidth(1);
   widget.setBorderStyle(borderULine);

Answer (score 0):

You can change the leading to design a line like that and after return to the previous leading

```
                contentStream.setLeading(5f);
                contentStream.newLine();
                contentStream.showText("------------------------------------");
                contentStream.setLeading(25f);
                contentStream.newLine();
```

Comment: tankyou Sarie ,